# Running validation before the record save

Tags: apex

I'm running some validations and the validations are that: 
Every Employee should have two languages (English & Spanish) associated with it language type. (Lang_Type__c)

Otherwise user should not able to save the record and throw the validation errors, the below code works but not all the time, sometimes the validations pass even though the validation should failed. To give you an example, the user able to Save the record just by adding the English (should add both English/Spanish for that specific lang_type__c)

```
Lang_type__c = picklist (first language, home language)
```

So if I select `lang_type__c = 'first language'  or 'home language'` then I should have both Language__c = English and Spanish

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean ValidateLanguage(Id empId)  
{
    List<Emp_Languages__c> langList =  [SELECT Id, Name, Language__c, Lang_Type__c FROM Emp_Languages__c WHERE Id =: empId];

    map<string, boolean> mapLang = new map<string, boolean>();

    for(Emp_Languages__c l : langList) 
    {
       if(String.isNotEmpty(l.Lang_Type__c)) {
          mapLang.put(l.Lang_Type__c, true);  
       }
       else {
          mapLang.put(l.Lang_Type__c, false);  
       } 
    }

    boolean validationPass = true;
    boolean hasEnSp = false;
    String employeeLang = ''; 
    boolean langEnglish = false;
    boolean langSpanish = false;

    for(Emp_Languages__c lang : langList) 
    {
       hasEnSp = mapLang.get(lang.Lang_Type__c);  
       if(!hasEnSp ) 
       {
         employeeLang = '';              
         if(lang.Language__c == 'English') 
         { 
           employeeLang = 'English';
           langEnglish = true;
         }
         if (lang.Language__c == 'Spanish') 
         { 
            employeeLang = 'Spanish';
            langSpanish = true;
         }
         ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'There should be two language English/Spanish');
         ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 

         validationPass = false;

   }
     return validationPass && langEnglish && langSpanish ;      
    }
```

just to give you an sample data:

```
should validation fail: 

Id     Name         Language__c       Lang_Type__c
1      test         English           first language
2      abc          Spanish           home language 

should validation pass:

Id     Name         Language__c       Lang_Type__c
1      test         English           first language
2      abc          Spanish           first language
```

Comment: can you verify your sample data you have provided?

Comment: Is that Language__c is multi-select picklist?

Comment: Language__c is a Text

Answer (score 0):

From the `langList` which is returned from your SOQL, prepare a `Set<String>` which will contain only Language__c. **Set will not contain duplicate**.

Verify the `Size of Set <2`, it will throw the error message.

Sample code will look like this:

```
List<Emp_Languages__c> langList =  [SELECT Id, Name, Language__c, Lang_Type__c FROM Emp_Languages__c WHERE Id =: empId];

Set<String> LangSet = new Set<String>();
String prevLangType=''; 
for(Emp_Languages__c l : langList) 
{   
   if(String.isNotEmpty(l.Lang_Type__c) && (prevLangType=='' || l.Lang_Type__c == prevLangType)) {
        LangSet.add(l.Language__c);
        prevLangType = l.Lang_Type__c;
   }       
}

if(LangSet.size()<2)
{
    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'There should be two language English/Spanish');
    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
}
```

Comment: that logic will not work, how do you know which languages the user have added? i can add two "English" language

Comment: Let me replicate it

Comment: @NickKahn updated my answer

Comment: I did not think of `Set` thanks for that, but I see that potential there is still an issue and the issue is `Lang_Type__c` so as i have said in my question every `Lang_Type__c` will have two language associated with it, based on the code you posted and the `Lang_Type__c` I have now is only two but this will increase up to 6 type, so how would you handle that? if i have select lang_type='first language' and lang='English' and again lang_type = 'home language' and lang = 'Spanish' will the above code will break

Comment: I think you want distinct languages irrespective of lang_type__c

Comment: It will not break

Comment: yep it failed the test...tested your code and it does not detect so here is you can duplicate the bug based on your code you have, add `Lang_Type__c ='first language'` and have `Language__c = 'English'` and create another record `Lang_Type__c ='home language'` and have `Language__c = 'Spanish'` the validation passed.. .which is not suppose to be.

Comment: can user select either first or home language? or both

Comment: user can select either first or home language and regardless what user selects it should have two languages associated with it.

Comment: @NickKahn updated the code with the use of prevLangType variable. It store the language type first time and every subsequent loop it will compare. It will work I think

Comment: sorry did not work either,  the loop is only pointer to the previous selection but i have tested like this: language='Spanish' and type = 'home language' when i save i get the validation which is good and then i went ahead add another language='English' and type = 'home language' and when i save then validation pass so far so good but when edit the same record and add another language='English' and i select type = 'first language' and save then it save successfully but in fact it should have give me the validation error.

Comment: You should put that validation in trigger